# Azure search domain (dns suffix)

Tags: azure

How can I keep the search domain in Linux on Azure?
if I set this manually to somename.com, it will always be "reddog.microsoft.com" after a reboot of the Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure, the DNS search suffix is configured via DHCP so the contents of resolv.conf is managed by the DHCP process.  The package responsible for this varies depending on the distro.  In Ubuntu (for example) the responsible package is resolvconf and its [config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/resolvconf.8.html) can be used to override the provided suffix if desired.

The "reddog" suffix is only given to VMs when you're using your own DNS servers, I presume this is the case?

Gareth (Azure)

Comment: Yes I'm using my own dns servers (ms dns). I there a way to set this anyware? What I have done now is a manual eth0 config on ubuntu in interfaces folder. I't looks like after a restart of the VM my setting is still there. The eth0 is now configured as static. Hope it will not be overwritten by any other changes in Azure.

Comment: If you add the search line (per resolv.conf man page) to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head then it will be included in resolv.conf each time the DHCP client updates it.  That means other DHCP values (such as IPs) will not be made static.